# Remove <b> tag from text

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to make a bold text non-bold using Greasemonkey. I have only found ways to remove the tag along with its text, but not a way to simply remove the tag itself.

So how do I make

```
<b>
some text
</b>
```

just

```
some text
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've only one TextNode inside each B tag.

```
b.parentNode.replaceChild(b.firstChild, b);
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DGTh5/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're dealing with elements, not a string:

```
function unwrapChildren(element) {
    var parent, node, nextNode;

    parent = element.parentNode;
    for (node = element.firstChild; node; node = nextNode) {
         nextNode = node.nextSibling;
         parent.insertBefore(node, element);
    }
    parent.removeChild(element);
}
```

Then call `unwrapChildren` with the `b` element. The above will move all of its child nodes (there's probably only one, a text node) into the `b` element's parent node where the `b` element is, and then remove the `b` element.