# Using JavaScript / jQuery, how do I remove the HTML tags of selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

In my application (a basic WYSIWYG text editor) I have a bold button which works, but I need to be able to de-bold text also.

*Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?*

---

### My code

```
function bolden ()
{ 
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("b");

    range.surroundContents(newNode);
}

function unbolden ()
{
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

    $(range).contents().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: this might hold your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851776/remove-b-tag-from-text

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/W76f4/1/

Comment: mmm, but I need to only remove the user selected <b> tag, how would I do that? Thanks

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/W76f4/4/

Comment: Thanks Arun, it works a treat :)  , just got to implement it for i/em tags etc. now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
function unbolden() {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var node = $(range.commonAncestorContainer)
    if (node.parent().is('b')) {
        node.unwrap();
    }
}
```

*Note: If the selected range is under a `b` element then then entire contents of the element will be unwrapped not just the selected text*